# Django model manager use_for_related_fields and ModelAdmin relationships

Tags: django, django-admin

I am having trouble getting my model manager to behave correctly when using the Admin interface. Basically, I have two models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    objects = models.EmployeeManager()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=45, primary_key=True)
    . . .

class Eotm(models.Model): #Employee of the Month
    date = models.DateField()
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    . . .
```

And I have an `EmployeeManager` class that overrides the `get()` method, something like this:

```
class EmployeeManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get(self, *arguments, **keywords):
        try:
            return super(EmployeeManager, self).get(*arguments, **keywords)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            #If there is no Employee matching query, try an LDAP lookup and create
            #a model instance for the result, if there is one.
```

Basically, the idea is to have `Employee` objects automatically created from the information in Active Directory if they don't already exist in the database. This works well from my application code, but when I tried to create a Django admin page for the `Eotm` model, things weren't so nice. I replaced the default widget for `ForeignKey` fields with a `TextInput` widget so users could type a username (since `username` is the primary key). In theory, this should call `EmployeeManager.get(username='whatever')`, which would either return an `Employee` just like the default manager or create one and return it if one didn't already exist. The problem is, my manager is not being used.

I can't find anything in the Django documentation about using custom `Manager` classes and the Admin site, aside from the [generic manager documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#controlling-automatic-manager-types). I did find a [blog entry](http://mitchfournier.com/?p=11) that talked about specifying a custom manager for `ModelAdmin` classes, but that doesn't really help because I don't want to change the model represented by a `ModelAdmin` class, but one to which it is related.

Comment: Unrelated note: I wouldn't recommend overriding the behavior of get in your EmployeeManager. Instead, I would override the get_or_create function. That does exactly what you're talking about here. There might be some cases where you want to get the exact record but don't want to necessarily create it if it doesn't exist. You can call get_or_create everywhere you want auto creation, like so: `emp, created = Employee.objects.get_or_create(username='johndoe')`. Just make sure it returns the object *and* `True` (if created from scratch) or `False` (if it already existed).

Comment: I avoided using the `get_or_create` method on purpose because I didn't want to imply that code can create an `Employee` object. I also want the `Employee` model to behave exactly like other models, but pull its information from the directory instead of the database.

Comment: So basically there are three scenarios: 1) Employee record exists; 2) it doesn't exist; or 3) it doesn't exist and no matching LDAP record exists (and therefore don't create a new Employee.  In which case, I would still recommend against using `get` unless you're 100% certain you will always expect a possible side-effect (Employee record creation) when calling `get`.

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly. I use `get` because that's exactly what's being done, get information about an `Employee`, nevermind that it might "create" a database record in the process. The database really only exists to store the additional information not stored in the directory. The use of `get_or_create` would imply that if the `Employee` didn't exist, it would be created, which is absolutely not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not be understanding what you're trying to do here, but you could use a custom Form for your Eotm model:

```
#admin.py
from forms import EotmAdminForm

class EotmAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    form = EotmAdminForm


#forms.py
from django import forms
from models import Eotm, Employee

class EotmAdminForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = Eotm

    def clean_employee(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['employee']
        return Employee.get(username=username)
```

That, in theory, should work. I haven't tested it.

Comment: I tried that, but the `clean_employee` method doesn't get called. I added another field `foo` as a test and created a `clean_foo` method, which does get called though.

Comment: Okay, it works if I manually specify the `employee` attribute of the `EotmAdminForm` instead of letting it be automatically added. Thanks for your help.